# Capture GivenName from CNContact

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, cncontact

I'm trying to capture the given name of a contact when the user selects that contact from the Contact Picker. 
Right now I'm using this method

```
 func contactPicker(_: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect: CNContact){
    print("Selected Contact")

}
```

It works but I don't see how I can get a reference to the contact object that was selected. I was trying to reference these properties [CNContact](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontact)

Comment: The second parameter passed to the method is the contact that they picked.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter is the selected `CNContact` object. Note the `contact`
next to the `didSelect` which is missing in your example. In your example you have to use `didSelect` parameter which is your `CNContact` but contact would be a much more expressive name.

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {

   print(contact.givenName)

}
```